# Why can't grafana send email?

Tags: email, smtp, monitoring, grafana, kubernetes-helm

Pull `grafana` helm chart from official site.

https://github.com/kubernetes/charts/tree/master/stable/grafana

Set email send configuration in `values.yaml` file:

https://github.com/kubernetes/charts/blob/master/stable/grafana/values.yaml#L363

```
[smtp]
enabled = true
host = smtp.gmail.com:587
user = sender@gmail.com
password = sender_password
;cert_file =
;key_file =
skip_verify = true
from_address = sender@gmail.com
```

Then install it at local:

```
$ helm install grafana
```

Test send email, failed. Don't know why.

[image]

Comment: Skip_verify is for self signed certs so that setting does not look correct.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably check grafana logs first:

```
$ kubectl logs <grafana-pod-name> --tail=20
```

Logs will have the error. I tried with gmail and had to enable `Allow less secure apps` under `Apps with account access` in security settings of gmail account.

P.S: I am using smtp port 465 for gmail.

Answer (score 1):

I think I know what is up.

The

```
user: 
password:
```

fields are not for your email address and password, but SMTP user and SMTP password credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a firewall issue. Please share the error logs